# Keep cells or magic functions from saving to python script

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to turn off magic functions or arbitrary cell blocks when saving ipython notebook to script?

I use the mode where saving the `.ipynb` file automatically saves to `.py` as well, but the magic functions I use break the script. I've tried things like

```
magic_cmd = """%cd ~/
%load_ext autosave
%autosave 30
"""
if in_ipython():
    eval(magic_cmd)
```

which apparently doesn't like magic functions and throws a SyntaxError (I'd rather not use `eval` anyways...). Is there some Javascript code I could use that just prevents the cell from saving?

So 2 parts to the question:

1. Is there any way to keep all magic functions from saving to script?
2. Is there any way to keep any arbitrary cell from saving to script, or, say, all cells below a certain point from saving to script (analogous to the 'Cell > Run all above' command)?

Comment: Must you need the resulting script to be run by python? If you add ipython executable in the #! line on top of the resulting .py script, it would run just fine.

Comment: I need it accessible by someone without ipython, so yes, it needs to be python-runnable for now. I'll have to look into that option for the future though--thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any way to prevent it from being saved to the script, but you can (1) add a test to ensure that the magics only execute in ipython, and (2) convert the basic magic syntax to a syntax that is acceptable to plain python

```
magic_cmds = """%cd ~/
%load_ext autosave
%autosave 30
"""
if in_ipython():
    for magic_cmd in magic_cmds.splitlines() :
        get_ipython().magic(magic_cmd[1:])
```

This works in both ipython and python, except that python obviously doesn't execute the commands.  Note that if you remove the `%` signs from your string, you should remove `[1:]` from the last line.

Personally, I prefer the following version because it catches the exception when `in_ipython` is not defined, though you could certainly add a `try` to the above in the same way.

```
try :
    if(__IPYTHON__) :
        get_ipython().magic(u'cd ~/')
        get_ipython().magic(u'load_ext autosave')
        get_ipython().magic(u'autosave 30')
except NameError :
    pass
```

### Edit

Cell magics can similarly be included.  For example, to translate an ipython cell

```
%%R -o x
x <- c(1,2,3)
```

you would write

```
get_ipython().run_cell_magic(u'R', u'-o x', u'x <- c(1,2,3)')
```

I can't find much information on this command beyond the built-in help text, but I think the arguments are pretty self-explanatory.  And of course, multi-line inputs can also be used in the third argument by inserting newlines ('\n') in the string.

More generally, if you want to translate something, just write it in a notebook, and then click `File` -> `Download as...` -> `Python (.py)`, and look in the script that you get out.

Comment: Quite verbose, but looks like the only doable solution so far. Thanks!

Comment: I've add a version more like your original.  Hopefully not too verbose.  :)

Comment: I prefer the try/except version... there's just not going to be a way to beat magic methods for conciseness...

Comment: @thias Yes.  My answer is too long to go in a comment, so I've edited my answer above.